# Conditional tags in javascript js file

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to use HTML conditional tags like `<!--[if (IE 6)|(IE 7)]>` inside a .js file as I need to execute certain javascript if visitor is using IE6 or IE7?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you're trying to do? It's bad to check which browser your client is using... if you tell us what you're attempting, we can come up with a better solution.

Comment: Or you can seperate the code in another JavaScript file which will only be implemented when IE 6 or 7 is in use

Comment: Well there is something similar for script with [`@cc_on`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ie/8ka90k2e(v=vs.94).aspx) but please don't use this (i only mention it that you know that it exists but that it is really bad), because with that you will have problems with minification, validation and other problems.

Comment: I use javascript to change the position of an element from absolute to fixed and when scroll up return it back to its original position...ie7 for some reason positions the element wrongly so I have to use different margin left value for it and older IEs

Comment: @MichaelSamuel then do it like `jquery`(if you want to use vanilla javascript)  and test for this behavior instead for checking which browser it is (you need to keep in mind that this behavior also depends on if IE is in quirks mode or not, so just checking for the version will probably fail later)

Comment: @MichaelSamule i need to correct myself `jquery` uses [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect?redirectlocale=en-US) for position calculations, which is a really nice technique if you only want to support ( IE 4+, Safari 4+, FF 3+). But the rest of my comment is still true, it is better to test for the wrong behavior then testing for the browser version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like this with the markup...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

Then in your JS, you can check for the appropriate body styles:

```
if (html tag has class lt-ie8) {
  // we're in ie7 and below land
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional comments in your markup, and use the result to create conditional variables in your js. Start your doc with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--[if lte IE 7]><html lang="en" class="ieDetect ie7Detect"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="ieDetect ie8Detect"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="ieDetect ie9Detect"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
```

I usually prefer to use jQuery for this and check for classes:

```
var ieDetect = $('.ieDetect').length
,   ie7Detect = $('.ie7Detect').length
,   ie8Detect = $('.ie8Detect').length
,   ie9Detect = $('.ie9Detect').length
;

if (ieDetect){
  // do stuff with IE
}
```

If you want to only use JS, you can either use a class fetching function and retain the markup above, or you could forgo the generic ieDetect class and just use ie7Detect (and 8,9) as IDs on the html tag.

```
var ie7Detect = document.getElementById("ie7Detect").length
,   etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate JS files are the best option.

However you can use navigator.userAgent:

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
```

From this you can determine the browser the user is using to view your page and use the if statement built into JS.

Comment: User agents can be spoofed and are therefore not reliable methods of determining a browser. You should look into ***feature detection*** and it's benefits as opposed to "browser sniffing". For an excellent implementation of this, look into [modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/).

Answer (score -1):

User `navigator.userAgent` to check the browser the user has.

Recommended reading: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Comment: User agents can be spoofed and are therefore not reliable methods of determining a browser. You should look into ***feature detection*** and it's benefits as opposed to "browser sniffing". For an excellent implementation of this, look into [modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: I put a link about "feature detection" in my answer, just after answering a way for checking for browser in Javascript. Did you even see it?

Comment: You did but you suggested that the OP use the `userAgent` object to check the browser which is completely unreliable...